# Can't open modal on cellClick

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, tabulator

I'm trying to get a modal to pop up on cellClick. I'm not getting any errors, but it's not working. The table still loads and my other functions run on cellClick, but not the modal. I'm using Vue, Tabulator, bootstrap.

```
<script>
  var Tabulator = require('tabulator-tables')
  export default {
    name: 'Test',
    data: function () {
      return {
        modalShow: false,
        tabulator: null, // variable to hold your table
        tableData: [
          {name: 'Billy Bob', age: '12'},
          {name: 'Mary May', age: '1'}
        ] // data for table to display
      }
    },
    watch: {
      // update table if data changes
      tableData: {
        handler: function (newData) {
          this.tabulator.replaceData(newData)
        },
        deep: true
      }
    },
    created: function () {
      console.log('Test', this.$refs)
    },
    mounted () {
      // instantiate Tabulator when element is mounted
      this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
        data: this.tableData, // link data to table
        layout: 'fitColumns',
        columns: [
          {title: 'Name', field: 'name', sorter: 'string', width: 200},
          {title: 'Age', field: 'age', sorter: 'number', align: 'right', formatter: 'progress'}
        ],
        cellClick: function (e, cell) {
          var name = cell.getRow().getCell('name').getValue()
          var value = cell.getValue()
          var field = cell.getField()
          console.log(name, value, field)
          return {
            modalShow: true
          }
        }
      })
    }
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div ref="table">
    <b-modal v-model="modalShow">Test</b-modal>
  </div>
</template>
```

Comment: Try this. change `return {modalShow: true}` to `this.modalShow = true`

Answer (score 0):

User @dagalti is almost correct - in their example, `this` would refer to Tabulator, so you have to capture the Vue instance at an elevated scope, in a variable I have named `self`.  See my modifications to your code, below.

```
mounted () {
  var self = this;

  // instantiate Tabulator when element is mounted
  this.tabulator = new Tabulator(this.$refs.table, {
    data: this.tableData, // link data to table
    layout: 'fitColumns',
    columns: [
      {title: 'Name', field: 'name', sorter: 'string', width: 200},
      {title: 'Age', field: 'age', sorter: 'number', align: 'right', formatter: 'progress'}
    ],
    cellClick: function (e, cell) {
      var name = cell.getRow().getCell('name').getValue()
      var value = cell.getValue()
      var field = cell.getField()
      console.log(name, value, field)

      self.modalShow = true;
    }
  })
}
```